# Bootstrap: как сделать прямую ссылку на модальное окно?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Есть бутстраповское модальное окно с id="myModal", которое на главной странице сайта открывается при клике на ссылку:

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Окно</a>
```

Как сделать (и можно ли вообще) прямую ссылку, чтобы при переходе сразу открывалось модальное окно?

Такой вариант не работает:

```
<a href="http://mysite.ru/#myModal">Ссылка</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить условие

```js
if (document.location.href.indexOf('showModal') != -1) {
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
}
```

И сделать ссылку такого вида:  http://mysite.ru?showModal

Она будет проверять наличие showModal в адресной строке и если оно там есть то отобразится попап

Comment: Тогда можно просто писать if (document.location.href == 'http://mysite.ru/#myModal'), и тоже будет работать. Спасибо!